# Branch io Unsubscribe

Tags: react-native, branch.io

How do you force an unsubscribe on branch i.o. I want to unsubscribe a user once he/she logs out from the app so that the subscribe will be called again once someone logs in from the same device.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by using the following steps:

1) Calling branch.logout() when the user logs out of the app. Docs: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/#track-users

2) Making sure any open/install session cache is cleared and unsubscribe is called by adjusting the Cache TTL. Docs: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/#adjust-cached-link-ttl

If you have already tried this and still facing issue let us know or write to us at integrations@branch.io and we'll be happy to provide you with the required support!